# Expo + firebase: Could not reach Cloud Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

Using Expo 44, my app can fetch Firestore content properly in Expo Go with `expo start`. But when publishing with `expo run:android`, it gives following error, while auth is working properly.

```
[2022-06-06T03:33:09.084Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.8.2): Could not reach Cloud Firestore 
backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds.This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it 
is able to successfully connect to the backend.   
Setting a timer for a long period of time, i.e. multiple minutes, is a performance and correctness issue on Android as it keeps the timer module awake, and timers can only be called when the app is in the foreground. See https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12981 for more info.
(Saw setTimeout with duration 392773ms)

Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1):
FirebaseError: Failed to get document because the 
client is offline.
construct@[native code]
```

I am using older version of firebase:

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app"
import firestore from 'firebase/compat/firestore';


const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: ",
  storageBucket:
  messagingSenderId: 
  appId: 
  measurementId: 
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = app.firestore();
export default app;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a silly mistake. In the Firebase console I uploaded my SHA1 and SHA256 for the EAS Play Store build, so Firebase couldn't recognize the local-build app, which is not signed by Expo EAS. It works perfectly if you build (with dev-client) using `eas build`.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your android emulator have internet connection or use Expo GO app on your physical smartphone.

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking